# Creating bitmap from short[]

Tags: c#, bitmap

```
public void CreateMaps()
{
    var GridWidth = GridSizeX;
    var GridHeight = GridSizeY;
    int stride = GridWidth * 3 * 2;
    byte[] bluegrid = new byte[GridHeight * stride];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < GridWidth * GridHeight; i++ , j+=6)
    {
        bluegrid[j] = (byte)(SelectedItem.BlueGrid[i] >> 8);
        bluegrid[j + 1] = (byte)(SelectedItem.BlueGrid[i] >> 8);
        bluegrid[j + 2] = (byte)(SelectedItem.BlueGrid[i] >> 8);
        bluegrid[j + 3] = (byte)(SelectedItem.BlueGrid[i] & 255);
        bluegrid[j + 4] = (byte)(SelectedItem.BlueGrid[i] & 255);
        bluegrid[j + 5] = (byte)(SelectedItem.BlueGrid[i] & 255);
    }

    JetColorMapBlueGrid = BitmapSource.Create(
                GridWidth,
                GridHeight,
                96.0,
                96.0,
                PixelFormats.Bgr24,
                null,
                bluegrid,
                stride
                );
}
```

This is my function, it is working however,
 i think i'm cropping a part of my array.
can you please look at the logic of transferring SelectedItem.BlueGrid[] which is a **short array** with size of (GridSizeX, GridSizeY) into a **byte[]**??

Comment: Stride is incorrect, formula is (width * bytes per pixel).

Comment: i'm using rgb 24, 3 bytes per pixel?

Comment: Yes, formula for bytes per pixel is : ((bits per pixel + 7) / 8). So in your case (24+7)/8 = 3. Note, use integers.

Comment: but i'm converting from short array to byte array so i have to multiply by 2

Comment: No you don't, the array you are creating the `BitmapSource` from is a `byte[]` so that's correct. What's unclear to me is how you fill it, it seems that the final result will only be two colors.

Comment: this is for testing of course i'm trying to create a jet map like in matlab, from an array of short[]. when i put stride = width *3, i get an index out of bound error.

Comment: Example for a 16*16 image, 16*16*3 : 768 bytes, stride: 48. You should post the code where you create that array of shorts.

Comment: ok your answer helped me i have figured it out thanks.